# java.util.Base64 Not found, can't use android.util.Base64 because class is a dependency used outside of Android

Tags: java, android, base64

I'm getting `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.util.Base64" on path: DexPathList` in an android application, and because an external decoder class used by both Android and another java application outside of android I can't use 'andorid.util.Base64' like so many people suggest. How do we resolve java.util.Base64 in android?

I couldn't find anything else to try, the only other answer I've seen is to use the android class. It's not an option.

This is the shared method to decompress messages that are in Base64, used both in Android and on the service.

```
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.getMessage());
    GZIPInputStream gzipStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gzipStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    final StringBuilder messageString = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        messageString.append(line);
    }
    messageJson = messageString.toString();
```

Comment: Which import did you do? For the rest i dont understand a word of your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to use java.util.Base64. The problem boils down to 'I'm trying to run this snippit of code in Android, but it can't resolve the class and I can't change the import to be android-specific because it's a shared class'

Comment: Encode is a smaal function. You could grab it from Android source code and put it in yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved it by using an apache library for Base64 encoding/decoding that both Android and Non-andorid could use.

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
 <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
     <version>1.13</version>
 </dependency>
```

---

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way to resolve this issue without including an additional dependency, by just using a higher API Level. The `java.util.Base64` is available since API Level 26 (Android 7.1 Nougat) which was released in 2016), see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Base64